# How can I register OCX after build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, activex, ocx

How do i set up a project to automatically register the OCX file that is created ?

I think there's an option in the properties somewhere, but i cant find it...

I'm using VS2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

**Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Register Output**

See [Linker Property Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/024awkd1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in MSDN

Comment: how can this be implemented in VS2019?